# Eclipselink Error while using Java Streams

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to use *Java 8 Streams* with *JpaRepository* to read data from a table but I am facing some issues.

Any idea how should I solve this?

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.HintValues;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.ResultSetConcurrency;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.ResultSetType;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.QueryHint;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.*;

@Repository
public interface CancelledDetailedHeaderRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = RESULT_SET_TYPE, value = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly),
            @QueryHint(name = RESULT_SET_CONCURRENCY, value = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly),
            @QueryHint(name = JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + 100),
            @QueryHint(name = SCROLLABLE_CURSOR, value = HintValues.TRUE)
    })
    @Query("SELECT h" + " FROM #{#entityName} h " +
            "WHERE h.status = ?1")
    Stream<Entity> findAllByStatus(String status);

}
```

Eclipselink properties:

```
  @Override
protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
    map.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "none");
    map.put("eclipselink.query-results-cache", "false");
    map.put("eclipselink.logging.logger", "JavaLogger");
    map.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "FINE");
    map.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "FINE");
    map.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
    map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.BATCH_WRITING, BatchWriting.JDBC);
    return map;
}
```

Exception Description:

> The method [getContainerClass()] is not a valid method to call on
>   object [ScrollableCursorPolicy(page size = 10)]

.

Comment: How did you configure EclipseLink in application.properties?

Comment: There are no configurations for Eclipselink in application.properties.

Comment: Maybe the ResullSetType.ForewardOnly and / or Scrollable_cursor hints changed the result type to somewhat like ScrollableCursor as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304917/queryhint-resultsettype-forwardonly-fails-with-spring-jpa-eclipselink